# Flat file import

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have 3M records TXT file need to import to a 2008 SQL table daily. When SSIS Job run it takes 9 hours to finish just the importing. If I use Import and Export Wizard manually then it only take 2-3 mins to import. Is there something wrong with SSIS script or that is how it works? I recreated the SSIS script 3 times already and still having the same issue. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: You know that you can get a SSIS package out of the Import/Export wizard, right? Why don't you compare that one to yours? Or better yet, just use that one.

Comment: SSIS can, and will, be as slow as you designed your package to be. In 2009, Microsoft showcased how to load 1TB of data into SQL Server using SSIS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). I personally achieved to load 2TB of data in under 40 minutes last year. Learn the tool and you will love it. Other than that, @marceln comment is what you should start looking at.

Comment: @marceln I'm new to SSIS. Could you instruct me how to "get a SSIS package out of the Import/Export wizard" ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per marceln comment, save the ssis import wizrd setting as ssis package.

See the [image]

In the attached screenshot you can see the checkbox option for saving the settings as ssis packa\ge.

Comment: I'm using SQL2008 Std but I dont have Save SSIS Package option. Please help!

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots??

Comment: figured it out... I was using SQL Management Studio 2012 for SQL 2008 Std, that is why. I have the option to save SSIS Package now. But will it import the same TXT file name or with any TXT file name? I have not run the package yet... would like to get some more info. Thanks.

Comment: The destination file name will be same. Also you can see the flat file destination connection manager in the connection manager area. Just try to understand the package, so that you could able to create your own.